# How do I resolve this error that keeps me from starting Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have searched documentation to this error that I have never seen before in working with Ruby on Rails. I just got a new MacBook and I installed Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.4 and when I attempt to run rails server, I get this error:

```
.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thread_safe-0.3.5/lib/thread_safe/cache.rb:155: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
```

How do I eliminate this error that is keeping me from starting up the Rails server?

Comment: Why are you installing ruby on a MacBook? Shouldn't you have a server for this?

Comment: is that the only error?

Comment: @Dev People install Ruby and Rails on MacBooks all the time. It's a great way to develop, then, when it's beyond proof-of-concept we move it to alternate hardware for testing and continue developing on the local version.

Comment: Yes, I do suppose Unix is an excellent development environment... Guilty as charged, I use it for developing Python applications (I have .py files littered all over the file system, I can't keep track of them all :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if that's the issue, since what you are seeing is just a warning. That warning appears because you are using ruby 2.4.0.

This version introduced this change: Unify Fixnum and Bignum into Integer

See here for the announcement: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/Z

The warnings come from the activesupport gem which is part of rails, and they will fix it soon.

Try downgrading your Ruby Version to 2.1 and try again.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41464223/3700798)