# 502 server error on gcloud with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, gcloud

I deployed an app right after cloning from github. I did bundle install and everything, and the server said

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:40: 
warning: Insecure world writable dir /google/gopath/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/home/hwangjinsong/.gems/gems/activesupport-
5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51: warning: constant ::Fixnum is 
deprecated
/home/hwangjinsong/.gems/gems/activesupport-
5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52: warning: constant ::Bignum is 
deprecated
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
/home/hwangjinsong/.gems/gems/activesupport-
5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:138: warning: 
constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
[2017-04-06 12:09:32] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2017-04-06 12:09:32] INFO  ruby 2.4.0 (2016-12-24) [x86_64-linux]
[2017-04-06 12:09:32] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=334 port=8080
```

but when I go to the page, https://agarlogin-1142.appspot.com/
it says

Error: Server Error

The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>502 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#ffffff"> 
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your 
request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</p></h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help:

This warnings appear because you are using ruby 2.4.0

[warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated When generating new model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463999/warning-constant-fixnum-is-deprecated-when-generating-new-model)

We don’t have to worry about this change most of the times in our application code. But libraries like Rails use the class of numbers for taking certain decisions. These libraries need to support both Ruby 2.4 and previous versions of Ruby.