# Ruby 2.4.1 - warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to StackOverflow and Rails, so I am hoping this is not too naive a question. I am trying to run my application locally using bin/rails server. When I type that, I receive the following trace:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

    /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
    /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
    Exiting
    /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
        from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /Users/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
         ... 5603 levels...
        from /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from /Users/name/spending-tracker-master/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I do not believe I can ignore it as stated here ([warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated When generating new model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463999/warning-constant-fixnum-is-deprecated-when-generating-new-model)) because it won't open the application locally.

Could someone help?

Thank you!
Ben

Comment: Try updating rails

Comment: Or if you could provide a [mcve], I'd give you a more definite answer.

Comment: Note the change introduced in Ruby V2.4 described [here](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/11/18/ruby-2-4-unifies-fixnum-and-bignum-into-integer.html).

Comment: You have two options: Downgrade Ruby to 2.3.x or upgrade Rails to 5.1.x. But that old version of Rails is just not compatible with the latest version of Ruby.

Answer (score 17):

Ruby 2.4 unified `Fixnum` and `Bignum` into a single class `Integer`. When Rails (ActiveSupport's [core extensions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) to be precise) attempts to monkey-patch the aforementioned classes, an error occurs.

This was [fixed](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26732) in Rails 5, and the fix was also backported to Rails 4.2 with [version 4.2.8](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2017/2/21/Rails-4-2-8-has-been-released/):

> Hi everyone,
>
> I am happy to announce that Rails 4.2.8 has been released.
>
> This is the first version of the 4.2 series that officially support
>   Ruby 2.4.

All you have to do is [upgrading Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) from 4.2.5 to Rails 4.2.8.