# Can't generate model in ruby on rails using linux mint 19

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, linux-mint

I run the following command on the terminal

```
Rails generate Welcome index
```

and I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sprockets/digest_utils.rb:47: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sprockets/digest_utils.rb:51: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:110: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:111: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `load_defaults' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000055dbd42fb448> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/sebastian/Documents/proyecto/bicitaxis/config/application.rb:26:in `<class:Application>'
    from /home/sebastian/Documents/proyecto/bicitaxis/config/application.rb:24:in `<module:Bicitaxis>'
    from /home/sebastian/Documents/proyecto/bicitaxis/config/application.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I have had lots of issues trying to use ruby on rails on linux, any suggestion on whether I should re-install or just switch to windows.

Ruby version: ruby 2.5.1p57
Rails version: Rails 5.2.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated When generating new model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463999/warning-constant-fixnum-is-deprecated-when-generating-new-model)

Comment: Seems like you missed the `model` argument after the `generate` command, or you did try that?