# warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated (4.2.0 rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
/home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
/home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
         ... 4101 levels...
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
```

I can not fix this error. I tried to upgrade to rails 5.0.0 (but I didn’t manage to upgrade)

```rb
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    active_model_serializers (~> 0.10.0.rc5) was resolved to 0.10.9, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.1, < 6)

    axlsx_rails (~> 0.5.0) was resolved to 0.5.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.1)

    haml-rails was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.0.1)

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.0)

    responders (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.4.1, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 6.0)

    rspec-rails (~> 3.0) was resolved to 3.8.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord-postgis-adapter (~> 3.1.4) was resolved to 3.1.5, which depends on
      activerecord (~> 4.2)

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.0.0)

    leaflet-rails was resolved to 1.5.1, which depends on
      rails (>= 4.2.0)

    react-rails (~> 1.6.0) was resolved to 1.6.2, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "resque":
  In Gemfile:
    resque (~> 1.26.0)

    resque-scheduler (~> 4.3.0) was resolved to 4.3.1, which depends on
      resque (~> 1.26)
```

ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x86_64-linux]

Rails 4.2.0

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.3

My maximum turns out to be updated to 4.2.11.1, but there are more errors.

Comment: [This stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41464223/7369429) may help you more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated When generating new model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463999/warning-constant-fixnum-is-deprecated-when-generating-new-model)